# How to insert a row to table which has a default value in column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, foreign-key-relationship, postgresql-9.1

I have such table:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: forum; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE forum (
    forum_id integer DEFAULT nextval('seq_forum'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    forum_name character varying NOT NULL,
    group_id integer NOT NULL,
    forum_parent integer DEFAULT (-1)
);


ALTER TABLE public.forum OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: PK_forum; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY forum
    ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_forum" PRIMARY KEY (forum_id);


--
-- Name: FK_group; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY forum
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_group" FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;


--
-- Name: FK_parent; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY forum
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_parent" FOREIGN KEY (forum_parent) REFERENCES forum(forum_id);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

As you see above, this table has (at least should have ...) a default value in column forum_parent. I want to insert some data to this table, I do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO forum (forum_name, group_id) VALUES('new forum', 1);
```

yup, I have a group with id = 1. But this code gives me:

```
PostgreSQL error: 23503 ERROR:  insert or update on table "forum" violates foreign key constraint "FK_parent"
DETAIL:  Key (forum_parent)=(-1) is not present in table "forum".

NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
```

How to make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement is correct. When you don't explicity declare the column name on your `INSERT` statement, the value that is inserted on the table is the default (*in your case, it's `-1`*).

But the problem lies on the referential constraint. The column `forum_parent` of table `forum` is dependent on the values of column `forum_id` of the same table. As this DDL says,

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY forum
       ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_parent" FOREIGN KEY (forum_parent) 
       REFERENCES forum(forum_id);
```

The `INSERT` statement failed during execution because the value `-1` is not present on column `forum_id`.

My suggestion is to change the default value from `-1` to `NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE forum 
(
    forum_id integer DEFAULT nextval('seq_forum'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    forum_name character varying NOT NULL,
    group_id integer NOT NULL,
    forum_parent integer DEFAULT NULL
);
```

The difference between `NULL` and `-1` is that `NULL` is simply unknow. or the value does not exist while `-1` is an existing numeric value.

Comment: Ok, now I get it but have another, connected question. How can I do that: my subforum can have a parent (other forum) then subforums `forum_parent` column points out to other forum id. But there also can be a situation that a forum doesnt have a parent (cause its a forum, not a subforum, thats why `forum_parent` should be -1)?

Comment: no, forums should have default value of `NULL` not `-1` so change the schema to `forum_parent integer DEFAULT NULL`. it is easy to query it, by the way, just use `WHERE forum_parent IS NULL` when you want to show only forums not subforums.

Comment: I did this: `alter table forum ALTER COLUMN forum_parent SET  default null;` thanks!:)

Answer (score 2):

You added the following constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY forum
 ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_parent" FOREIGN KEY (forum_parent) REFERENCES forum(forum_id);
```

Which basically says that forum_parent must match an existing value of forum_id. You probably don't have a row with `forum_id = -1` and therefore it fails.

You'll need to create a row with `forum_id = -1` and only then can you use that default value...

Another option is to put the default value to be **null** since `forum_parent` is nullable

Comment: I know that I dont have a forum_id = -1 but I wanted `-1` to be the default value in this column when I dont pass a forum_id with `INSERT` statement ..

Comment: @Katie you can't have a default value that contradicts the foreign key.

Comment: hmm, so how can I do that: my subforum can have a parent (other forum) then subforums `forum_parent` column points out to other forum id. But there also can be a situation that a forum doesnt have a parent (cause its a forum, not a subforum, thats why `forum_parent` should be -1)?

Comment: @Katie If it doesn't have a parent, the forum_parent should be null... When you create the table, change the forum_parent's deceleration to: `forum_parent integer DEFAULT (NULL)`

Comment: OK, cheerz I will do this like you suggested:)